# Can't get Current Culture name of my system?

Tags: vb.net

I changed my current culture to English(Australia)
and default is English(United States)

I try with this to get current culture name but i wont get it.

```
Dim Culture = new Globlization.Cultureinfo(LCID)
```

note : i used data base of another system and configure in my system.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way :

```
Dim Culture = Globlization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

or if you want name string in `Culture` instead of `CultureInfo` object :

```
Dim Culture = Globlization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name
```

[[For Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)]